# How to print to PDF the first page of two sheets then combine with a cover page?

Tags: excel, vba

I send out a PDF packet to clients after an auction.

I am trying to export page 1 sheet 1 with page 1 sheet 2 as PDF then combine with a cover page and 3 supplemental pages (which I have a Word doc or PDF).
Both sheets are divided into 20 printable pages with a page breaks.
Each page on "bidder checklist" is 5 columns wide, 34 rows high and on "bond sheet" 6 x 48.

Below is a long macro to export all 20 Excel pages as different files. I can then combine the cover, combined PDF, and supplemental with Adobe Pro but that is tedious.

Any ideas to make the macro shorter?

```vb
Sub Export_CheckBond() 

    Path = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"
    BookName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 17)
    ExportName = BookName & "Combined"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'page1   
    worksheets("Bidder Checklist").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:E34"
    worksheets("Bond Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:F48"
    
    worksheets(Array("Bidder Checklist", "Bond Sheet")).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=Path & "2_" & ExportName & "1", _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False
    
    'page2
    worksheets("Bidder Checklist").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A35:E68"
    worksheets("Bond Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A49:F96"
    
    worksheets(Array("Bidder Checklist", "Bond Sheet")).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=Path & "2_" & ExportName & "2", _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False
    
    'page3 through page 20 all the same

    Sheet11.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Sheet12.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Sheet01.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not make it any more elegant but here is the workaround I came up with for combining the files:

I copied the cover and supplemental pages in Word, paste specials in a new Word doc, paste as image. I copied that image into new sheets and made sure they fit the print print area, which took a little messing around to make sure the margins worked. All I had to do then was add the cover and supplemental sheets to the array. Please be advised, The order in the array does not matter, they print in order of tabs, left to right.

I first tried exporting the pdf to jpg/png/tiff and taking a screen shot, but they were either fuzzy looking or made the excel file huge. Using word you are able to un group to slightly move things around and it retained the original quality.

Thank you for reading. I hope this can help someone else in the future!

```
 Sub Export_CheckBond() 

    Path = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"
    BookName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 17)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'page1   
    worksheets("Bidder Checklist").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:E34"
    worksheets("Bond Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:F48"
    worksheets(Array("Packet Cover","Bidder Checklist", "Bond Sheet", "Packet Sup")).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=Path & BookName & "Quota Packet 1", _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    'page2 through page 20 all the same

    Sheet11.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Sheet12.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Sheet01.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```